Safely removing unrecognised snaps and snap itself
I have a Ubuntu system on which I installed Firefox, Ubuntu directed me to using snap. I no longer need Firefox on this system and find snap's effect on lsblk etc to be confusing. I would like to remove it.
Related questions whose answers I have read:

How to completely remove snap and replace with flatpak?
How to remove Snap completely without losing Firefox?
how to remove snap packages after removing snap?

From reading those related questions, I believe I need to individually remove all snaps before removing snap itself. I don't recognise most of these snaps and suspect they are all dependencies of firefox that are not removed when removing firefox
$ sudo snap list
Name                       Version                     Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare                       1.0                         5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core18                     20240920                    2846   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core20                     20240911                    2434   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core22                     20241001                    1663   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
firefox                    133.0-2                     5361   latest/stable    mozilla✓    -
gnome-3-28-1804            3.28.0-19-g98f9e67.98f9e67  198    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-3-38-2004            0+git.efb213a               143    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gnome-42-2204              0+git.510a601               176    latest/stable    canonical✓  -
gtk-common-themes          0.1-81-g442e511             1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snap-store                 41.3-72-g80e7130            1216   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd                      2.63                        21759  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
snapd-desktop-integration  0.9                         253    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -

Can I safely sudo snap remove --purge {packagename} for all of these in the order shown or is there something else I should do?

Yes, remove those snaps one by one and then remove the snapd package

Yes but do you still want a GUI (graphical windows interface)?
The following link tells you how to install the Mate GUI which you might want to do first. (It is my understanding this is still a apt package.)
From a 22.04 perspective (at least dated 08/23)
https://itsfoss.com/install-mate-desktop-ubuntu/

Then follow the instructions in the link to remove all the snap packages. But note this includes Gnome and Firefox and Thunderbird (if you still have the default install). Then finally how to remove snapd.
From a 22.04 perspective.
https://www.debugpoint.com/remove-snap-ubuntu/
Good Luck
